# rsync copies to local instead of remote

Tags: command-line-interface, rsync, duplicity

I've got a problem with my previously working backup-script.

In short it simply calls duplicity and orders it to copy files via rsync to a NAS.

However when I now start my script, it returns always a permission denied Error.

I've narrowed it down to rsync not working as I thought it would.

In my test setup I now execute the following code:

```
rsync -av test/ remoteuser@nas.domain.com
```

What happens is that in the current directory a folder called "remoteuser@nas.domain.com" is created and rsync syncs the files from test into that new folder.
If I append the target-directory on the remote (...:/home/remoteuser/backup) it returns the previously mentioned "Permission denied" error

```
Permission denied, please try again.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Connection via ssh to my nas works without a problem btw.

Comment: It can't determine the target is a system to connect to because you've not used the usual `:` at the end.

Comment: If I do, this is the error I get:

Permission denied, please try again.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]

Comment: Try as `rsync -e -e "ssh -v" -av test/ remoteuser@nas.domain.com:` - it sounds like you've got an ssh access issue to the remote system (e.g. keys being provided by an agent on the desktop, but when run in a script it doesn't have access to the key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, but I have found the solution:

Rsync needs to run on both the client and the server to be able to sync files. I've checked if rsync was installed before, and it was. But when I tried to copy on the NAS with rsync a testfile locally, I got an error that the service was not running.

I found out that for some unknown reason it is needed to pass the path to rsync as option in the call as following:

```
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/syno/bin/rsync ...
```

Now the script works again!

As a sidenote:
Since I use duplicity I had to write my full command as following:

```
duplicity --rsync-options="--rsync-path=/usr/syno/bin/rsync" ~ rsync://remoteuser@nas.domain.com:/home/remoteuser/backup
```

Comment: That's a known reason - it's because the remote side rsync is not in a standard location. In future, for questions like this you're better off asking on superuser.com as it's not actually a programming question

Comment: Yes, i realised that after I've written the question :/

Comment: to me this does not solve. the real problem is that you have to put : after user@server as @Petesh said.